# How to implement (unique) page views tracking in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

On my app I have different pages where users can interact with. What I need is the following. I want to track:

1. How many users are on each page?
2. How many unique users are on each page?

I want to track the data without google analytics, because I want to analyse the data myself.

Comment: Do use google analytics, do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I want to track the data and use it in my grails application to make data analysis.

Comment: So what? Use api to pull data and use it. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed

Comment: So I think the OP could simply edit his question and say "I know I could do this with GA, but I'd rather do it myself" and then someone could say "Ok, in that case, here's how you might approach this..."

Comment: There are many good reasons to avoid GA, including wanting to track access to non-public pages, or pages that may contain secured or private information.

Comment: use `awstats`, works on your server

Comment: @IgorArtamonov is there a Grails plugin for awstats?

Comment: it's a Perl script, for processing web server logs. So it doesn't matter what language/framework you're using, you don't need any plugin or something, it's just server configuration. just google 'awstats' for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Grails Filter:

```
class TrackingFilters {
    def trackingService

    def filters = {
        access(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (!session.user) {
                    trackingService.trackIpAddress(getIpAddress())
                } else {
                    trackingService.trackUser(session.user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Grails filters are pieces of code that you can make grails execute before and after a request.
You specify which controllers, and which actions are affected by using the modifiers.

You create filters by using the command
    grails create-filters example.Tracking

The name that you choose is on you alone.

Then you can7 define a filter in tyhis generated skeleton class, (i created the "access" filter, applying to all controllers and actions)

Inside the filter you can access request and session, so you should be able to use this context to track your users, for example:

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
request.getHeader("Client-IP")
```

To be perfectly pedantic: trackingService is a hypothetical service implemented by you.

Comment: Can you explain your code a little? What das it do? What is trackingService doing? How does trackIpAddress gets the IP?

Comment: I did not realize that you were asking about the whole implementation here, from how to hook your code into grails to how to actually write your code. I will update my answer with a general explanation of what Grails filters are, but I have no time to reimplement google analytics for you ;-)